# How to update where the files are stored in Django app

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app that contains multiple models with FileField. I am saving by default every file directly in the Media folder. But as the app grew larger also Media folder became bigger. Now my idea is to move the files into separate folders split by models. So I am wondering what is the best practice when it comes to this?
Shall I move the files to separate folders, then manually update every file location in the Database and then update Filefield path for every model? Or is there better approach?

Comment: Instead of manually updating the locations, I'd [write a data migration to do it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). The same migration could also move the physical files if you feel like it.

Comment: AKX could you please give some example of a migration how I could do this if I want to move all files in given model from media to media/modelname folder?

Comment: (1) Make a dict of source -> dest paths: `ps = {f.name: f"model/{f.name}" for f in MyModel.objects.values_list("file", flat=True}` (2) Loop over the dict, call `os.rename()` (assuming you're using filesystem storage) (3) Update the model values (untested, but should work): `MyModel.objects.update(file="model/" + F("file"))`.

Answer (score 0):

To organize files by models in a Django app: Create subdirectories for each model in the media folder, update upload_to paths in FileFields, move existing files, and test.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='modela/')

class ModelB(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='modelb/')
```